# Ifelse(V>=80,"Above_Average","Average") in R printing extra spaces between last 2 outputs

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-operator

I've a simple programming exercise in R, where I have to-
Check each value of the vector V passed as a argument. If the marks are greater than or equal to 80 print Above_Average. If the marks are less than 80, print Average(in a single line).

Here's what I'm doing :-

```
conditional <- function(V)
{
ifelse(V>=80,"Above_Average","Average")
}
conditional(c(90,80,85,70,95))
```

output :-

```
[1] "Above_Average" "Above_Average" "Above_Average" "Average"       "Above_Average"
```

My concern is the extra space between last two outputs.
Do you've any idea why I'm getting the extra space? And what is the solution for this?

Comment: What extra space?

Comment: @user2974951 It's visible now.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Answer: beats me :(.

Comment: Why are you concerned about this? It's just a print.

Comment: The output is spaced in the console so each element uses the same space as the element with the maximum width.  Compare `conditional(c(90,80,85,70,95)); conditional(c(90,80,85,80,95))`.

Comment: I can't find relevant post or documentation link for the explanation right now but it is something along the lines "the print output in the console always prints vector output with equidistant lengths". See the distance in output of these 2 vectors `c('a', 'abcdefghif')` and `c('a', 'b')`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
ifelse(V>=80,"Above_Average","Average")
```

use:

```
cat(ifelse(V>=80,"Above_Average","Average"))
```

This will do!

--

For example:

```
conditional <- function(V)
{
  W <- ifelse(V>=80,paste("Above_Average_Marks"), paste("Average"))
  cat(W)
}

conditional(c(90,80,85,70,95))
#> Above_Average_Marks Above_Average_Marks Above_Average_Marks Average Above_Average_Marks
```

Answer (score 2):

This removes the extra space:

```
conditional <- function(V)
{
    x <- if_else(V>=80,"Above_Average", "Average")
    paste(x, collapse= ' ')
}

conditional(c(90,80,85,70,95))
```

```
[1] "Above_Average Above_Average Above_Average Average Above_Average"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have got it.

I think that when you have a vector which will return `Above_Average` as well as `Average`, it spaces all the elements with respect to the length of the greater character string, i.e. `Above_Average`. So when you run:-

```
conditional(c(90,80,85,70,95))
```

You get

```
[1] "Above_Average" "Above_Average" "Above_Average" "Average"       "Above_Average"
```

If you were to change `Above_Average`, to `Above_Average_Marks`, we get even
bigger space.

```
conditional <- function(V)
{
  ifelse(V>=80,paste("Above_Average_Marks"), paste("Average"))
}
conditional(c(99, 90,80,85,70,95, 100))

[1] "Above_Average_Marks" "Above_Average_Marks" "Above_Average_Marks" "Above_Average_Marks" "Average"             "Above_Average_Marks" "Above_Average_Marks"
```

Answer (score 0):

these are not spaces. it's just a length alignment.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
conditional <- function(V) 
{
  
    for (i in V){
        if(i>=80){
            cat("Above_Average ")
            }
        else{ 
            cat("Average ")
            }
    }
}

conditional(c(78,85,90))
```